# Visual Studio WebTestRequest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webtest

I need some help with WebTestRequest on visual studio

I have 2 requests that the 2nd request need some data from the 1st request response

how do i use the specific data that i need from the 1st response to the 2nd request ? (in my case its `Sessionid`)

Test requests:

```
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting;


public class WebTest1Coded : WebTest
{

    public WebTest1Coded()
    {
        this.PreAuthenticate = true;
        this.Proxy = "default";
    }

    public override IEnumerator<WebTestRequest> GetRequestEnumerator()
    {
        WebTestRequest request1 = new WebTestRequest("https://xxx.xxx.com/api/xxx");
        request1.Method = "POST";
        request1.QueryStringParameters.Add("format", "json", false, false);
        StringHttpBody request1Body = new StringHttpBody();
        request1Body.ContentType = "application/json";
        request1Body.InsertByteOrderMark = false;
        request1Body.BodyString = "{\"UserName\":\"xxx\",\"Password\":\"xxx\"}";
        request1.Body = request1Body;
        yield return request1;
        request1 = null;

        WebTestRequest request2 = new WebTestRequest("https://xxx.xxx.com/api/xxx");
        request2.Method = "POST";
        request2.QueryStringParameters.Add("format", "json", false, false);
        StringHttpBody request2Body = new StringHttpBody();
        request2Body.ContentType = "application/json";
        request2Body.InsertByteOrderMark = false;
        request2Body.BodyString = @"
          RequestHeader"": 
  ""SessionId"""": ""xxx"",
  ""ApiKey"""": ""xxx""

        request2.Body = request2Body;
        yield return request2;
        request2 = null;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to do in the original Web Test file than in a Coded web Test. Just add an extraction rule to the first request. It saves the value into a context parameter which can then be used in the second request.

If you really want to use a Coded Web Test then you might create a sandbox web test with a suitable extraction rule and context parameter usage. Then convert that to Coded and copy the interesting bits into your test.

An `ExtractText` rule to extract text between `abc` and `def` and store the results in the `acbdef` context parameter generated the code below.

```
WebTestRequest request3 = new WebTestRequest("http://localhost/");
request3.ThinkTime = 1;
request3.ParseDependentRequests = false;
ExtractText extractionRule1 = new ExtractText();
extractionRule1.StartsWith = "abc";
extractionRule1.EndsWith = "def";
extractionRule1.IgnoreCase = false;
extractionRule1.UseRegularExpression = false;
extractionRule1.Required = true;
extractionRule1.ExtractRandomMatch = false;
extractionRule1.Index = 0;
extractionRule1.HtmlDecode = true;
extractionRule1.SearchInHeaders = false;
extractionRule1.ContextParameterName = "abcdef";
request3.ExtractValues += new EventHandler<ExtractionEventArgs>(extractionRule1.Extract);
yield return request3;
request3 = null;
```

Other extraction rules have different properties that will need to be given values. I recommend putting the main details of what you want into the web test and then doing a generate code to find out exactly what C# code is necessary.

The extracted value is used in three places in the next request:

```
WebTestRequest request4 = new WebTestRequest(
    ("http://localhost/" + (this.Context["abcdef"].ToString() + "/more")));
request4.ThinkTime = 1;
request4.ParseDependentRequests = false;
request4.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("Use-abcdef-again",
   ("pqr" + (this.Context["abcdef"].ToString() + "stu"))));
request4.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("Use-abcdef",
    this.Context["abcdef"].ToString()));
yield return request4;
request4 = null;
```